# Castle Active Record - Usage in .net 2.0

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

Quick question:

Can I use the latest release of Castle Active Record in .net 2.0 projects (build against .net 2.0 CLR)?

I looked through the site for a .net 2.0 release and could not find it. The latest binary release has only .net35, .net4, .net40cp.

Interestingly enough, when I compile and run my sample (in Visual Studio 2005) against the .net35 castle active record binaries the sample runs fine.

Again, is it safe to use .net35 active record build with .net 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be precise: Castle ActiveRecord 3.0RC (currently the latest release) requires .NET 3.5 or higher. .NET 3.5 runs on the CLR 2.0.

Comment: NET 3.5 runs on the CLR 2.0? Can you prove that? I never heard of 3.5 running on CLR 2.0! I need MSDN or some other reliable reference.

Comment: Never mind. Found source on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history